# How to connect to MySQL database via plain text file?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, file, text

I would like to improve my code so that it would be possible to connect to the database using a text file, but not setting the database connection from the IntelliJ or Eclipse view only from the text file (we set the login, password, path, etc. there).

```
public class SQL {
    public static Connection Connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("loc:/xyz.txt");
        props.load(in);
        in.close();
```

The problem is with this line:

```java
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("loc:/xyz.txt")
```

How can I set the path to the `FileInputStream` with a txt file?

So far, I can set the login, password and URL using a text file, but I still have a problem how to correctly pass the address of this text file (in a text file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, java properties files have the `.properties` extension. I would suggest that you name the file `jdbcconn.properties`. Put that file in the same folder as file `SQL.class`. Then in your java code you can do something like the following.

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
java.io.InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("jdbcconn.properties");
props.load(is);
```

Refer to *javadoc* of class `java.lang.Class`

Note that in Eclipse IDE, you create the `jdbcconn.properties` file in the same folder as file `SQL.java` and when you build your project, Eclipse will automatically copy file `jdbcconn.properties` to the same folder as file `SQL.class`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to configure you application from an `external source`. Lucky enought, `Java` provides an API that helps manage your external configuration as `keys/values` with the [properties files](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

By default your configuration file has `.properties` extension, i.e. `config.properties`. If you are using a `maven` project, your configuration file will be in this folder `/src/main/resources`.

Then you will be able to call your file as mentionned in the previous answer.